# How to get a percentage over the total at each hierarchical level in Analysis Services

Tags: ssas

I have inherited a multidimensional OLAP cube (SQL Server 2014) and I currently need to extend it to produce the output I need.

Currently, I have a loan book by Report Date and then I need to get the proportion of the loan book by Geography.

An example hierarchy would be:
CY2018 > CY2018 Q3 > Jul CY2018 > Australia > Victoria > 3000
and then display the fields, Current balance and Proportion of Loan Book.

Or, alternatively I might want to see the proportion of loan book for Victoria over the entire loan book on a particular date.

Proportion of loan book is a calculation of the balance at a particular level in the hierarchy divided by the All balance for the loan book on a particular date.

For example:
If you are looking at Feb 2017 and Victoria, then I would like to see the proportion of the loan book for Feb 2017, Victoria over the entire balance for Feb 2017.

If you are looking at April 2018 and postcode 3000, I would like to see the proportion of the loan book for postcode 3000 in April 2018 over the entire balance for April 2018.

If you are looking at Jan 2016 and Australia, then you would see 100%, being the total loan book for that month.

The proportion of the loan book will always be calculated over the current month selected. It makes no sense to calculate a proportion of a loan book over multiple months or quarters etc, but I wouldn't care if that happened as a side-effect of what I am trying to achieve.

At the moment I have created a Calculated Member called Proportion of Loan Book as follows:

```
Case  
    When IsEmpty( [Measures].[Current Balance] )   
    Then 0  
    Else ( [Geography].[Geography Key].CurrentMember,  
           [Measures].[Current Balance]) /  
         ( [Geography].[Geography Key].[All],   
           [Measures].[Current Balance] )  
    End
```

This produces something like this:
[image: Cube image]

The problem with this is that it (1) doesn't take into consideration the current month, and (2) only shows a proportional value at the very bottom postcode level. I've fudged the figures here. but Victoria, for example, should show as 36% of the loan book for Jul 2018, whereas at the moment it shows as 100%.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured it out I think. Here's my code:

```
    Case  
    When IsEmpty( [Measures].[Current Balance] )   
    Then 0  
    Else ( [Geography].[Geography Key].CurrentMember,  
           [Measures].[Current Balance]) /  
         ( Root([Geography].[Geography Key].[(ALL)].[ALL]),   
           [Measures].[Current Balance] )
    End
```

I don't know how correct it is; I pretty much stumbled around until something worked!